# How can I read strings from a file which has data in bytes format?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, crud

I am making a CRUD app from Flask. It randomly generates a number of passwords based on user input. The user also gets the ability to save the input inside a CSV file and then printing the output on the terminal.

Here is the source code

**exec_prog.py** (for creating the web interface)

```
from Password_creator import *
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,redirect,url_for
from csv import *
from table import Table
from flask_modus import Modus
from werkzeug import secure_filename
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='template')
modus= Modus(app)


@app.route("/")
def data_input(): # for user input for suggestions
    return render_template('input.html')


@app.route('/data-extract') # for extracting the user input
def data_extract():
    global sug
    sug = int(request.args.get('sug')) # to get the user input
    return redirect('/generate/new') # redirecting to generate



@app.route('/generate/new') # for generating the passwords
def generate():
    global final_g
    global data_x
    global password
    final_g = [] # for the passwords
    password = []
    for i in range(sug):
     v =  password_generator("","","") #for calling the class
     alpha_g = v.alpha_rand_func()    # line 25- 30; please refer the Password_creator.py file                 
     sym_g = v.symbol_rand_func()
     int_g = v.int_rand_func()
     spec_g = v.special_number_production()     
     final = v.final_output 
     final_g.append(v.final_output)
     passwd_obj = Table(v.final_output,'nil') # for storing them in a class 
     password.append(passwd_obj) # for storing them in a list
    return redirect('/generate/show-output')


@app.route('/generate/show-output',methods  = ["GET","POST"])
def show_output():    
    return render_template('output_disp.html',final_lst = password) # rendering the output_disp.html


@app.route('/generate/<int:id>',methods = ["GET","PATCH","POST"]) # for modifying the function
def show(id):
     found  =  next(entry for entry in password if entry.id == id) # for finding the entry with the required id
     if request.method  == b"PATCH": # for dealing with PATCH 
        found.passwd = request.form['edit_passwd']
        found.desc = request.form['description']
        return redirect('/generate/show-output')
     return render_template('modify.html',found_entry = found)

@app.route('/generate/file-manip-disp') # for displaying the uploading and downloadng options for password
def disp_manip_menu():
  return render_template('file-manip.html')

@app.route('/generate/file-manip',methods = ["GET","POST"]) # for uploading the passwords
def save_file():
  pass_output_lst = [] #for passwords
  desc_output_lst = [] #for descriptions of the password
  encrypted_pass_output_lst = [] #storing passwords after encryption
  encrypted_desc_output_lst = [] #storing descriptions of passwords after encryption
  
  if request.method == "POST": # checking if the request method is POST
    pass_file = request.files['fileName'] #requesting the name of the password saving file
    pass_file_Name = secure_filename(pass_file.filename) #storing the name of the password saving file
    key = Fernet.generate_key() # generating a key
    key_init = Fernet(key)  # storing the key for encrypting purpose
    key_file = request.files['keyfile']  # requesting the key saving file
    key_file_name = secure_filename(key_file.filename) #storing the name of the key saving file
    for i in password:
      encrypted_pass_output_lst.append(key_init.encrypt(bytes(i.passwd,encoding = "utf-8")))  #line 79 -80: storing the passwords and descriptions
      encrypted_desc_output_lst.append(key_init.encrypt(bytes(i.desc,encoding  = "utf-8")))   #by converting them into bytes and then encrypting them
    with open(pass_file_Name,"w") as k: #for writing the password and description in the required file
      writer_param = writer(k,delimiter=":",quoting = QUOTE_NONE,quotechar=" ") #csv writer
      for i in range(sug):
        writer_param.writerow([encrypted_pass_output_lst[i],encrypted_pass_output_lst[i]]) # writing the contents of the list
    with open(key_file_name,"wb") as k: # for writing the key in the required file
      k.write(key)
    return render_template("file-manip.html",message = "file saved succesfully") 
@app.route('/generate/file-manip-upload',methods = ["GET","POST"])

def upload_file(): #for uploading the file
  encrypted_pass_output_lst = []
  encrypted_desc_output_lst = []
  Upload_key = "" #for storing the key
  if request.method == "POST":
    Uploadfile= request.files['Uploadfile'] #requesting the name of the required file
    Uploadfile_req = secure_filename(Uploadfile.filename) #storing the name of the password saving file
    Uploadkeyfile = request.files['Uploadkeyfile'] #requesting the name of the key storing file
    Uploadkeyfile_req = secure_filename(Uploadkeyfile.filename) #storing the name of the key storing file
    with open(Uploadkeyfile_req,"rb") as k: #for reading the data of the key storing file and storing it in  Upload_key
      Upload_key = k.read()
    Upload_key_init = Fernet(Upload_key) # for storing the key for decrypting purpose
    with open(Uploadfile_req,"rb") as k: # opening the password-storing file
      reader_param =  reader(k,delimiter=":",quoting=QUOTE_NONE,quotechar=" ") #csv reader
      for arr in reader_param:
        encrypted_pass_output_lst.append( Upload_key_init.decrypt(arr[0]) ) #line 105-106: storing the passwords and descriptions in the 
        encrypted_desc_output_lst.append( Upload_key_init.decrypt(arr[1]) ) #respective variables by decrypting them first
        print(encrypted_pass_output_lst,encrypted_desc_output_lst) #printing the lists

      
  return render_template('file-manip.html',message = "file uplaoded succesfully")
```

**Password_creator.py** (for generating the passwords)

```
from random import *
from itertools import *
import string
class password_generator():  
   def __init__(self,final_output,special_nproduction,final_specp): #creating the local variables
       self.final_output = final_output
       self.special_nproduction = special_nproduction
       self.final_specp = final_specp
      
      
   def alpha_rand_func(self): #for randomly selecting alphabets
       alpha = string.ascii_letters
       for i in range(4):
           self.final_output += choice(alpha)
        
   def symbol_rand_func(self): #for randomly selecting symbols
      symbol = string.punctuation
      for i in range(3):
         self.special_nproduction += choice(symbol)
             
   def int_rand_func(self): #for randomly selecting integers
      integer = string.digits
      for i in range(2):
         self.special_nproduction += choice(integer)
        
   def special_number_production(self): #for concatenating the integers and symbols
          self.special_nproduction = list(self.special_nproduction)
          init_perm = list(permutations((self.special_nproduction),5))
          selected_comb_init_list = choice(init_perm) #selecting a permutation of integers and symbols randomly
          mod_selected_comb_init = "" #for storing the permutation in the form of a variable
          for i in selected_comb_init_list: #iterating through the selected_comb_init_list
             mod_selected_comb_init += i 
          self.final_output += mod_selected_comb_init  # adding the integer-symbol combination to final output
   def final_output_production(self): #for concatenating all the characters, selecting a combination of it randommly and returning it as output
           return self.final_output #returns the final output
####################################          

####################################
```

**table.py** (for storing the passwords generated)

```
class Table(): #class for storing the passwords with their description
    count  = 1
    def __init__(self,passwd,desc):
        self.passwd = passwd
        self.desc = desc
        self.id = Table.count
        Table.count += 1
```

**str_main.html**(base html file)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        {%block content%}
        {%endblock%}
    </body>
</html>
```

**input.html** (for user input)

```
{%extends 'str_main.html'%}
{% block content %}
<div id  = "suggest-input">
    <form action  = "/data-extract" method = "GET">
      <input type ="number" placeholder="no. of suggestions", name="sug">
      <input type= "submit" ,value = "click here">
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**output_disp.html** (for showing the output required)

```
{% extends 'str_main.html'%}
    {% block content%}
    <div id  =  "options">
      <div id  = "btn-output-1"><h6>Upload file</h6></div>
      <div id  = "btn-output-2"><a href="{{url_for('data_input')}}"><h6>Home</h6></a></div>
      <div id  = "btn-output-3"><a href ="{{url_for('disp_manip_menu')}}"><h6>Save</h6></a></div> 
    </div>
    <div id = "output-head">
      <h1>Here are the suggestions</h1>
    </div>
    <div id  = "output-div">  
      <form id = "output-data" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">   
        <table>
             <tr>
               <th>Password</th>
               <th>Description</th>
             </tr>
             
             {% for i in final_lst %}
            <tr>    
               <td> <a href ="{{url_for('show', id  = i.id)}}">{{ i.passwd }}</a></td> 
               <td>{{ i.desc }}</td>
            </tr>     
             {% endfor %}
        </table>
        
      </form>
    </div>   

{% endblock %}
```

**modify.html**(for modifying the passwords generated)

```
{% extends 'str_main.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div id  = "modify-div">
<form id = "edit" action = "{{url_for('show',id  = found_entry.id)}}?_method=PATCH" method ="POST">
   <input type = "text" value = "{{found_entry.passwd}}" name = "edit_passwd">
   <input type = "text" value  ="{{found_entry.desc}}" name = "description">
   <input type ="submit" value = "save change" >
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**file-manip.html** (for file manipulation)

```
{% extends 'str_main.html' %}
{% block content %}
<p>Saving file</p>
<form method= "POST" action = "/generate/file-manip" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
    <label>For the password storing file</label>
    <input type = "file" value = "browse" name = "fileName">
    <label>For the file storing the key</label>
    <input type = "file" value = "key file" name = "keyfile">
    <input type ="submit" value= "saving file">

</form>
<p>Uploading file</p>
<form method= "POST" action = "/generate/file-manip-upload" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
  <label>For the password storing file</label>
  <input type = "file" value = "browse" name = "Uploadfile">
  <input type = "file" value = "key file" name = "Uploadkeyfile">
  <input type ="submit" value= "saving file">


</form>
<br/>
<p>{{message}}</p>

{% endblock %}
```

When I chose the required files for printing the passwords in the terminal, I am getting the following error.

```
    for arr in reader_param:
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

I tried to change the mode of reading and writing in required parts of the code but nothing worked. So I would like to know what is causing this error and how can I resolve the issue.